# c# starting a .exe file from current file path + folder + exe file

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Im trying to have a exe file opened on click, its going to be in a subfolder of a file path, I dont want to put in c:\folder due to file install will be different for each user, I would like to use file path + another folder in that file path to + "file.exe"

Any ideas?

Comment: "." Is current folder...(for others I think question is about relative file paths)

Comment: Process.Start("folder\file.exe");

Comment: Have tried that and a few other things, tying to find best

Comment: Cant use exact location, going to be having a self installer to programs folder, so if 64bit will put in different program folder, so tying to use file location + "folder\updater.exe"

Comment: Look into the appdomain.currentdomain methods

Comment: If I understand right, you do not ask how to run a process, you ask how to manage the path to it. If this is the case, you should use a registry entry. When application installs on a computer it usually keeps a registry entry (used for un-install later on).  
This is how you should work, locate the value you or your installation added to registry and read the installdir value.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code smple

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process.Start(<"your file path");
    }
```

for example if you wish to run notepath++ then

you path will be=@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\Notepad++.exe

Comment: could I use something like :

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.StartupPath + @"\updater\AutoUpdate.exe");

Comment: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Notepad++\Notepad++ it works for me

Comment: it had to do with a permissions issue, I just need to have the Process.Start have permission to file location to run the exe